# Is there a good way to implement an authentication / authorization check at the Actix route level?

Tags: authentication, routes, rust, rust-actix

My API routes are collected into a scope like so:

```
.scope("/api", |s| s
        .nested("/doorlock", routes::doorlock)
        .resource("/config{path:.*}", |r| {
            r.get().with(routes::config::read);
            r.put().with(routes::config::write);
            r.delete().with(routes::config::delete);
        })
)
```

I am thinking about adding a route-level protection, something that would either pass-through or return a `401 Unauthorizated` response like so:

```
.scope("/api", |s| s
        .filter(is_authenticated_and_authorized)
        .nested("/doorlock", routes::doorlock)
        .resource("/config{path:.*}", |r| {
            r.get().with(routes::config::read);
            r.put().with(routes::config::write);
            r.delete().with(routes::config::delete);
        })
)
```

Unfortunately, this will forward requests to the default handler rather than returning an error response in case it does not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [middleware](https://actix.rs/docs/middleware/).

You can then add your middleware to the scope:

```
// Create middleware
struct AuthMiddleware;

impl Middleware<AppState> for AuthMiddleware {
    fn start(&self, req: &mut HttpRequest<AppState>) -> Result<Started> {
        unimplemented!() // implement your auth logic here
    }
}

// later:

App::with_state(my_state)
    .scope("/api", |s| s
        .middleware(AuthMiddleware) // add your middleware to the scope
        .nested("/doorlock", routes::doorlock)
        .resource("/config{path:.*}", |r| {
            r.get().with(routes::config::read);
            r.put().with(routes::config::write);
            r.delete().with(routes::config::delete);
        })
);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the any extracted information in the Middleware can be "saved" into the request using the `.extensions()` map.

Comment: Adding middleware to a scope is really helpful to know--from the actix docs, I wasn't aware you could add it in to any level beside the root/app level.

Comment: Note: This answer doesn't apply anymore on actix 4.x+